# How to Visualize data in Apache Kudu?

Tags: data-visualization, apache-kudu

*Is it possible to visualize data in Apache Kudu? Is there any guideline for it?*

Comment: Asking for tutorials or broad guidance like this is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read [ask] to see what types of questions can/can't be asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Kudu itself does not have any built-in data visualization tool. Just like Oracle is an RDBMS and it does not come with a data visualization tool either. However, there are a few options:

1. Built a custom visualization tool yourself by using Java, Python or C++ API. https://kudu.apache.org/docs/developing.html.
2. Impala is a SQL engine that has built-in integration with Kudu. It also supports ODBC/JDBC driver. Thus you can hook almost any BI tools to Impala to query the data in Kudu and build visualization.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Arcadia Data` visualization which directly connects to Kudu tables without Impala connection. And Arcadia is built specially for Big data applications, which resides on distributed cluster. **[Distributed visualization tool for distributed computing]**